# Reshaping only a few columns in a dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to reshape a dataframe in R. Here is the dataframe I have in dput:

```
dput(newdata)
    structure(list(var1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), var2 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), var3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Date = structure(c(15260, 
    15260, 15260, 15169, 15169, 15169), class = "Date"), Success = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("var1", 
    "var2", "var3", "Date", "Success"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Output I am look for:

```
Variable    Date    N   Y
var1    3/2/2012    0   1
var1    3/4/2012    0   1
var1    3/6/2012    0   1
var2    3/2/2012    1   0
var2    3/4/2012    1   0
var2    3/6/2012    1   0
var3    3/2/2012    0   1
var3    3/4/2012    0   1
var3    3/6/2012    0   1
```

I am fairly new to R. I have been trying to use reshape() module but been unsuccessful until now. Any insight would be hugely appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: can you use `dput()` on your data to print the structure here?

Comment: I don't feel like wading through all the html to try to fix the formatting. Don't use the code snippet functionality to display data. Use `dput` as suggested, and if you want to show a few rows, just copy&paste them and format them as a code block.

Comment: Also, please show something you have tried.

Comment: Apologies, I am very new to SO. Here, the confusion

Comment: Ok - now what do you want the output to look like? What columns are you trying to reshape? the var1-3 columns to turn from wide to long?

Comment: That's right @Matt. And changing the Success column from long to wide.

Comment: got it. Let me check it out.

Comment: You're going to need to provide an example of how you want this to look. You have a duplicated row for Success. Do you want the number of successes as the column? You mentioned changing the Success column which would mean a Yes and a No column, so what should the value be underlying it? I'd create a view of how you want this to look and post it.

Comment: Hi @Matt, I have updated the post for the output. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for providing reproducible input and desired output. This helps a lot. Unfortunately as your input is presented now is flawed: rows 2 and 3 in your data frame are identical, and so are rows 5 and 6. It would not be possible to perform your desired data transformation correctly on such data.

Assuming your duplicate rows are not relevant, you can accomplish your desired output via `tidyr::spread()` and `tidyr::gather()`. I call your data structure `df`:

```
library("dplyr") 
library("tidyr")

# call to duplicated() removes all identical rows from df 

wide <- df %>%
  filter(!duplicated(.)) %>% 
  gather(Variable, value, starts_with("var")) %>% 
  spread(Success, value, fill = NA, drop = FALSE)

wide
        Date Variable N Y
1 2011-07-14     var1 0 0
2 2011-07-14     var2 0 0
3 2011-07-14     var3 0 0
4 2011-10-13     var1 0 0
5 2011-10-13     var2 0 0
6 2011-10-13     var3 0 0
```

Comment: I'd recommend `distinct()` instead of `filter()` + `duplicated()` here.

Answer (score 0):

So as kgolyaev stated, you have duplicate rows which means that spread can't simplify down to a single row when spreading the columns. One way around this is to just use a `mutate` with `ifelse` instead of spreading. This works because you just have "N" and "Y" for Success values. Had it been 12 unique values, it would have been a different solution.

We can gather the `vars` into `vars` and `num`. And then we can just use a simple nested `ifelse` statement to get the 1s and 0s. Then remove unneeded columns and arrange by `Date`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% gather("vars", "num", -c(Date, Success)) %>%
        mutate(Y = ifelse(Success == "N", 0, 1),
               N = ifelse(Success == "N", 1, 0)) %>%
        select(-c(Success, num)) %>%
        arrange(Date)


         Date vars Y N
1  2011-07-14 var1 1 0
2  2011-07-14 var1 0 1
3  2011-07-14 var1 0 1
4  2011-07-14 var2 1 0
5  2011-07-14 var2 0 1
6  2011-07-14 var2 0 1
7  2011-07-14 var3 1 0
8  2011-07-14 var3 0 1
9  2011-07-14 var3 0 1
10 2011-10-13 var1 1 0
11 2011-10-13 var1 0 1
12 2011-10-13 var1 0 1
13 2011-10-13 var2 1 0
14 2011-10-13 var2 0 1
15 2011-10-13 var2 0 1
16 2011-10-13 var3 1 0
17 2011-10-13 var3 0 1
18 2011-10-13 var3 0 1
```